# How to use two similar dependencies?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, material-design

In my app, I use a `BottomAppBar` which only works if I use the dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'`. Also, I use an `ExtendedFloatingButton` that can be used by using the dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'`. In my case, that means that I need to use both dependencies, but the compilation fails with `AAPT: error: attribute fabAttached (aka com.example.myapp:fabAttached) not found.`, which is an attribute of `BottomAppBar`.

So, the point is, I need to use one of them, where as if I would only use the latest version of those dependencies (the latest one `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'` according to [Google’s Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) and [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material)), then the `BottomAppBar` does not work any more.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't do it. Just use the latest stable 1.1.0 and you can use both components.

Comment: No really, somehow that dependency does not support both views. I change my architecture and use only stable one as you suggested. Thanks.